# Inverse Laplace of $\frac{1}{(s^2+1)^2}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I am a math student at freshman university level and I am taking an ODE class. I am not expected to integrate in the complex plane or to know convolution (so no duplication with [Inverse Laplace of $\frac 1 {(s^2+a^2)^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075025/inverse-laplace-of-frac-1-s2a2n)). The way we've done inverse Laplace in this class is by using the basic properties of Laplace Transform and referring to known Laplace transforms like sin, cos, and polynomials)

I don't know where to start but I know a first step is to consider that $$\mathcal{L} (t\times \cos t)= -\frac{d}{ds}\frac{s}{s^2+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

You have that
$$\mathcal{L} (t\times \cos t)= -\frac{d}{ds}\frac{s}{s^2+1}=\frac {s^2-1}{(s^2+1)^2}$$
$$\mathcal{L} (\sin t)= \frac{1}{s^2+1}=\frac {s^2+1}{(s^2+1)^2}$$

Substract ...

Comment: oh I see, If i subtract, I get $$ \frac{-2}{s^2+1)^2 $$ and  can just take the constant out

Comment: its just a constant....Laplace transform is a linear operator @JohnA. $L(af)=aL(f)$